# switching between enum states with touch

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have a simple player class like this:

```
enum State: Int {

   case dead, alive, idle

    }

class Player {

    var playerSprite : SKSpriteNode
    var currentState : State


init(passedInState: State) {

    currentState = passedInState
    self.playerSprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "playersprite.png")

    switch currentState {

        case .dead:
            println("Player is dead")

        case .alive:
            println("Player is alive")

       }

  }
 }
```

In my main class i create an instance of the Player class and try to change the players state by tapping on it in the touch method like so:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        let player1 = Player(passedInState: .alive)
        self.addChild(player1.playerSprite)
        player1.playerSprite.position = CGPointMake(100, 100)
}


override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    for touch in touches {

        let touch = touches.anyObject() as UITouch
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        var locationSprites = nodesAtPoint(location)

        for bla in locationSprites {

        (bla as Player).currentState = .dead

        }
    }
}
```

I always get a crash when touching the Sprite. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Where does it crash, and what's the error?

Comment: it crashes on touching the SKSpriteNode. The error is here: libswiftCore.dylib`swift_dynamicCastClassUnconditional:...

Comment: Just a side note: I would suggest that you start each case with an uppercase letter, like apple does in the swift documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there's a downcast failure, and in your code I see there are 2 forced donwcasts:

```
let touch = touches.anyObject() as UITouch
```

and

```
(bla as Player).currentState = .dead
```

I presume the error is in the last one, so I suggest setting a breakpoint and inspecting `bla` to check whether it's actually an instance of `Player`. Basing on your logic, if it can happen that it is not an instance of `Player`, I recommend using optional downcast:

```
if let player = bla as? Player {
    player.currentState = .dead
}
```

The advantage is that if `bla` is not an instance of `Player`, the if block won't be executed, instead of making the app crash.

---

Comment follow up

If you want to do some custom processing when the player status changes, you can add a property observer to the `currentState` property of the `Player` class:

```
var currentState : State {
    didSet {
        switch currentState {                
        case .dead:
            println("Player is dead")

        case .alive:
            println("Player is alive")

        case .idle:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that actually solved the crash issue.
One more question: my console did not output "Player is dead". Shouldn't it log that message after switching to currentState = .dead?

Comment: No, if the code you're referring to is in `init`. That doesn't add an observer, it's just executed once when the initializer is invoked. See updated answer

Comment: The custom processing is actually what i'm trying to achieve. However. If i add the property observer to the currentState property in my player class i still don't get any console feedback. I put it in the class level together with the declaration of currentState

Comment: That's because I made a mistake in my code :) updated now, check it out

Comment: Though the code seems correct,i'm still not getting a log output.
i think he never executes:

    if let player = bla as? Player {
    player.currentState = .dead
}

i put the log message println("Player is dead") in there and it does not show up as well. Any idea why this is not happening? Thanks for taking your time btw

Comment: No it doesn't stop either

Comment: That means that code block is never executed - which in turns means there's no sprite castable to `Player`. I think the error is that `nodesAtPoint` returns an array of `SKNode`, which is not castable to `Player`. Maybe you should inherit `Player` from `SKSpriteNode` rather than creating that as a `Player` property...  but honestly I don't have experience with SpriteKit, so that could even be a bad suggestion

Comment: Okay, actually I just came from inheriting from SKSpriteNode. I tried this approach to separate the graphics from the code. But you are probably right. I will try to rewrite the code. Anyways. Thank you very much. Didn't think about the property Observers